# How can I listen for events that are not implemented by all possible classes?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

In my MEF-based application, some modules use forms, but some do not.

I want to be able to respond to the closure of these forms, but can't seem to figure out how to do so. Module types are based on interfaces and those that use a form inherit a base class which inherits from `Windows.Forms.Form`.

E.g.

```
public partial class SwatchForm : ModuleForm, IAcquisition
```

Where

```
public partial class ModuleForm : Form
```

Since not all things that inherit `IAcquisition` (or my other module interfaces) inherit from `ModuleForm`, I tried this:

```
if (this.AcquisitionModule.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ModuleForm)))
{
    (ModuleForm)(this.AcquisitionModule).ModuleFormClosed += whatever....
}
```

But it still complains that `IAcquisition` has nothing called `ModuleFormClosed`.

I thought about using exceptions instead, but that feels like a bit of a hack. Is there a way to do this using events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` has a higher precedence than a cast, so you need to place the parentheses differently. Furthermore, you can check the type in a simpler way. Try

```
if (this.AcquisitionModule is ModuleForm) {
    ((ModuleForm) this.AcquisitionModule).ModuleFormClosed += ...
}
```

Another way is

```
var moduleForm = this.AcquisitionModule as ModuleForm;
if (moduleForm != null) {
    moduleForm.ModuleFormClosed += ...
}
```

Comment: Hah! That was simpler than I feared. Moving the brackets was all it took. Will accept when I can (5mins).